# Can I use amaretti cookies in a cheesecake crust?

Tags: baking, cookies, crust, cheesecake, crumb-crust

I'm making a cannoli cheesecake from this recipe (http://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/recipes/a43604/cannoli-cheesecake-recipe/).  I will be adding 1-2 tsps of cinnamon to the cheesecake batter and possibly almond extract.  All the recipes say to use a graham cracker crust, but that doesn't seem like it would be as authentic.  Can I use crushed (ground) amaretti cookies, like in the cookies below?  It seems like it would behave similarly to graham crackers or Nilla wafers.

Again, I'm asking about the crust and the use of a different cookie (since I've never used something outside of wafers or graham crackers or Oreos for crusts).  I understand that this will not be actual cannolis but a cheesecake designed to remind you of a cannoli.  I've updated the title as well so hopefully my request for help is clearer.

[image]

Comment: "Cannoli cheesecake" doesn't sound very "authentic" to me - cannoli are deep-fried rolls of dough.

Comment: Thank you Stephie.  That was very helpful.  I *know* what cannolis are.  And I understand that a cannoli cheesecake isn't the same as an actual cannoli, but I'm trying to get it as close as possible in cheesecake form.  I had hoped that it was understood that I actually do know the difference between a real cannoli and cheesecake.

Comment: Hi OP.  Please can you expand/explain the cannoli part of your question, because as @Stephie states it is dough.  Edit:  Sorry my comment came in at the same time as yours.

Comment: I think using all amaretti might create a crust that bakes too flat and too hard, since they contain no flour and are all egg white, sugar, and almond paste. For that same effect, you could use a mixture of shortbread cookies (such as Walker's) and almonds, along with about 1/4 teaspoon of almond extract. Run it all through the food processor and add the melted butter.

Comment: Thank you Dorothy.  I know some flours aren't really flour but ground whatever (almonds, rice, etc.) and they still work in place of wheat flour.  I wasn't sure with these cookies since I've never used them.  I liked the almond flavor they would have imparted but don't like the flat, hard crust you suggested they might create (which is probably very accurate now that I see they don't have any real substance).

Comment: Sounds nice to me.

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can. Just blitz the cookies in a food processor, and add a stream of melted butter until you can form the crust into a ball in your hand. Then just press the cookie mixture into the pan you want to bake the cheesecake in.

Comment: I concur. Just about the only function the cookies have in the "graham cracker" crust is to sit there, look nice, be delicious & soak up liquids if the need arises. No need to perform other chemical reactions. Any dry cookie can do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I would hesitate to use amaretti for the crust. As Dorothy stated, they are related to macarons, baiser and other egg-white-based cookies. I'm afraid they'd give you a very rubbery crust or soak up too much liquid from the filling. You want something "sturdier", and graham crackers or any other "robust" cookie fits the bill. If you use a cookie with lots of fat, you might want to play with the crumb-to-butter ratio a bit to prevent greasiness.

You also wanted to be "authentic", so if I read your questiin correctly, tasting "more Italian". 
But in this case, there is no need to use amaretti for the almond or amaretto flavour for "authenticity", a cannolo siciliano does not have amaretto anywhere, at least judging by a quick scan of recipes online.

Comment: I swear I hate the internet sometimes!  I found several recipes two days ago that all had almond (in some form - sliced, paste, extract) in the ingredients (even when I looked up cannoli recipes).  Now every recipe I see has white wine and lemon juice and/or zest.  *sigh*  I just don't want to end up with a cinnamon chocolate chip cheesecake.  I do agree that the amaretti cookies wouldn't turn out well.  I sort of feel like I should rethink the whole cannoli cheesecake thing.  LOL

Comment: And you're right that I want it to taste as much like an actual cannoli but in cheesecake form.  I'd make actual cannolis but the self life isn't as good, hence the cheesecake idea.

Comment: @Brooke for that, you might buy premade cannoli shells, crush and use them for the crust, and make a ricotta pie filling. That would hold longer, and could be frozen.